# How to find the positions of a range with same values in a vector in R

Tags: r, position, range, element

I have the following vector:

```
z=(0,0,0,1,2,1,2,2,1,2,0,0,2,1,2,2,0,2,0,0,1)
```

I use `rle(z)$lengths` and the output is:

```
3 1 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 2 1
```

which means that I have three `0's`, then one `1`, etc.

How can I have an output showing me the positions in which I have the three `0's`, etc.

For example, the positions of the first three `0's` is `1,2,3`.

Note that I want only the positions for which I have `rle(z)$lengths>1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `rleid` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
data.table(z)[, do.call(paste, c(as.list(unique(range(.I))), sep=":")), rleid(z)]$V1
#[1] "1:3"   "4"     "5"     "6"     "7:8"   "9"     "10"    "11:12" "13"    "14"    "15:16" "17"    "18"    "19:20" "21"
```

If we need to keep it as `numeric`, then it may be better to have a grouping column and the sequence column

```
data.table(z)[, .I, .(grp = rleid(z))]
```

---

Or if we are using `rle` from `base R`

```
v1 <- sequence(rle(z)$lengths)
unname(tapply(seq_along(v1), cumsum(v1==1), 
     FUN = function(x) paste(unique(range(x)), collapse=":")))
#[1] "1:3"   "4"     "5"     "6"     "7:8"   "9"     "10"    "11:12" "13"    "14"    "15:16" "17"    "18"    "19:20" "21"
```

and similarly for `numeric` vectors, the 'v1' can be `split` up into a `list` of `vector`s

```
split(seq_along(v1), cumsum(v1==1))
```

Comment: This does not work since the output should be:
"1:3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7:8" etc. How can I do this?

Comment: @VassilisChasiotis  Could you show the expected output

Comment: @VassilisChasiotis  Is it only for the 0's position?

Comment: @For everything that creates a range. The 0's is just an example. Note that I do not want to use just as an output. I want for example to use the 1:3 as 1st, 2nd, 3rd positions. I do not want logical values as output.

Comment: @VassilisChasiotis  Ok, got it, corrected both the methods

Comment: @arkun How to use the output as not locigal characters but as numeric?

Comment: @VassilisChasiotis  It is not logical characters, It is `character` class as you have a non-numeric character `:` in it.  It is not possible to have the `:` and also being a numeric class.  Perhaps you can keep it as a `list` of `vector`s

Comment: @arkun I understand! So, how can we have the range: `1,2,3` as numeric class?

Comment: @VassilisChasiotis  If we look at the first solution, `data.table(z)[, .I, .(grp = rleid(z))]`  you have all the info of a group and the new column sequence Or with second solution `split(seq_along(v1), cumsum(v1==1))`